# How to run a static analysis and coverage on the whole AOSP directory?

Tags: static, continuous-integration, code-coverage, android-source, analysis

In spite of the numerous modern tools in 2018, I would like to know how to run both line and branch coverages as well as static analysis on the whole AOSP directory (which tools, good pratices, methodology).

Obvious ways until the hardest ? Is it android-studio or ide dependent ?
Except CTS, anything else ?

Hope I am not looking in the right place but it seems there is a lack of documentation about it.

I currently try to setup building pipelines with Jenkins as the conductor of all of it and I'am spending a lot of time to understand how to correctly setup Firebugs, PMD, Android-Lint, jacoco, build warnings and so on.
I feel lost around all that tools.

I rely on your expertise to share your point on the subject.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For AOSP source code analysis we use codesonar . Codesonar provides support for  C, C++ and Java .

Refer below artilce for a better understanding on how Codesonar works along with PMD and FindBugs .

http://news.grammatech.com/grammatech-introduces-static-analysis-java

It is a paid tool and you can try out a 30 day trail .

http://go.grammatech.com/

Answer (score 0):

Codesonar is an expensive solution and there is no existance of a free (or open-source) version.

What's the truly different between Codesonar and Sonarqube (or any sonarqube-like solution) ? 
Knowing that Sonarqube supports all the language you enumerate and integrates both PMD and FindBugs as well.